# What values should be placed in headers in AWS DynamoDB API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a beginner, trying to use the AWS DynamoDB through API. I'm first starting with the `PutItem` method. (ref. link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#API_PutItem_Examples) Also, I am using postman for trial purposes.

---

The API documentation says it's a **POST** method call, and the headers required are as follows (cropped from the docs of DynamoDB API) -

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

Host: dynamodb.<region>.<domain>;
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: <PayloadSizeBytes>
User-Agent: <UserAgentString>
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Credential>, SignedHeaders=<Headers>, Signature=<Signature>
X-Amz-Date: <Date>
X-Amz-Target: DynamoDB_20120810.PutItem
```

I have some questions on the what to add as header values for different headers, please view them below -

- In the `Host` header, I have managed to make the value till '`dynamodb.ap-south-1 (region)`'. What should be added in the place of `<domain>`?
- Should the `Accept-Encoding` header, be left as it is? i.e. No change to 'identity' there?
- In the `Content-Length` header, it says to add `<PayloadSizeBytes>` value - does this mean the length of total string I am providing?
- What value should be placed in the `User-Agent` header? What does that mean?
- In the `Authorization` header, from where can I obtain the `Credential`, `SignedHeaders`, and `Signature` values?
- In what format should I provide the date to the `X-Amz-Date` header? Should it be 'dd/mm/yyyy' or something else?

---

Any support would be appreciated :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should be much easier to make API calls to DynamoDB by using the AWS SDK in your favorite language. The AWS SDK hides most of the HTTPS & header complexity.
https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

But, to prepare a call using raw HTTPS, here is a code sample that works for me in Node.JS.  You will need to generate your own Access Key & Secret Key and paste them into the creds {} section.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

This sample also uses "aws4" to sign the request.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4

It is calling ListTables, if this works you should be able to modify it for the other DynamoDB operations too. Be sure you have at least one table created first in us-east-1 (N. Virginia).

```
const https = require('https');
const aws4  = require('aws4');

const opts = {  
                service: 'dynamodb', 
                region: 'us-east-1', 
                path: '/',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
                    'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.ListTables'
                },
                body: '{}',
                endpoint:'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
            };

const creds = {
    accessKeyId:'AKIAJMM7I6LFNAAAAAAA',
    secretAccessKey:'3MPF019i8UFaRPbTX6ica2fy3h1tVVVVVVVVVVVV'
};

const signed = aws4.sign(opts, creds); 

const req = https.request(signed, (res) => { 
    console.log('statusCode: ' + res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', d => {
        const resObj = JSON.parse(d.toString());
        console.log(resObj.TableNames);
    });

});

req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('error : ' + error);
});

req.write('{}');

req.end();
```

Comment: Hi, Rob! Thanks for answering my question! :) It seems you have provided a full-fledged api module, and I wouldl like to know only the headers listed - can you please highlight where you used them in your answer's code, and from where you got them? Thanks a lot again!